# glTexImage2D failing in GLUT/FreeType example with OpenGL 3 and above

Tags: c++, opengl, freetype, glteximage2d

I'm using the example found here: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Modern_OpenGL_Tutorial_Text_Rendering_01

The issue is that when I specify an OpenGL context with a version above 3, ie:

```
glutInitContextVersion (3, 2);
```

Calling glTexImage2D results in a GL_INVALID_ENUM (as reported by GLIntercept) error and the output of the example is blank. As far as I can tell from the OpenGL 3.3 reference, this should only be happening if type is not a valid type constant or target is an invalid target.

Here is the offending line:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_ALPHA, g->bitmap.width, g->bitmap.rows, 0, GL_ALPHA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, g->bitmap.buffer);
```

Also, I have tried modifying the example to resize the bitmap so it's dimensions are the nearest power of 2, as in the NeHe tutorial ( http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/freetype_fonts_in_opengl/24001/ ), however I still got the same error.

I've also tried implementing the example using GLFW and have the same problem.

I'm using different shader loading code to the example, but shaders both compile/link fine and the example still works if I'm not specifying a modern OpenGL version.

If it helps my environment is: 
Windows 7 64-bit, Visual Studio 2010
AMD HD6950 Graphics with Catalyst 12.3 drivers.

Software libraries are:
FreeGLUT 2.8.0
GLEW 1.7.0
FreeType 2.4.9
glm-0.9.3.0

---

For reference, here is gliLog.txt - I've omitted the most of the end of the log since it's the same error recurring over and over again.

```
GL Intercept Log. Version : 0.5    Compile Date: Dec  3 2005    Run on: Fri Jun 22 15:42:05 2012

===================================================
Diagnostic: Unknown function wglCreateContextAttribsARB being logged.
GL ERROR - Function wglGetPixelFormat(0x200110ef) generated error GL_INVALID_ENUM
GL ERROR - Function glGetString(GL_VERSION) generated error GL_INVALID_ENUM
GL ERROR - Function glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS) generated error GL_INVALID_ENUM
...
InterceptShaderGLSL::CreateObjectPost - Unknown object type 0x8dd9
InterceptShaderGLSL::DeleteObjectPost - Unable to find shader ID 2
GL ERROR - Function glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,GL_ALPHA,27,35,0,GL_ALPHA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,0x73ab670) generated error 0x0500
ImageSaveManager::Save2DImage - invalid width/height on image
InterceptImage::SaveTextureImage - Error saving image 1
GL ERROR - Function glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP,0,4) generated error 0x0502
GL ERROR - Function glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,GL_ALPHA,20,35,0,GL_ALPHA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,0x73ac300) generated error 0x0500
ImageSaveManager::Save2DImage - invalid width/height on image
InterceptImage::SaveTextureImage - Error saving image 0
GL ERROR - Function glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP,0,4) generated error 0x0502
GL ERROR - Function glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,GL_ALPHA,23,28,0,GL_ALPHA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,0x73ac580) generated error 0x0500
ImageSaveManager::Save2DImage - invalid width/height on image
InterceptImage::SaveTextureImage - Error saving image 0
```

And here is the example code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
/* Using GLM for our transformation matrix */
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>
/* Using FreeType 2 for rendering fonts */
#include <ft2build.h>
#include FT_FREETYPE_H
#include "shader_utils.h"

#pragma comment(lib, "opengl32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "glew32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "freeglut.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "freetypeD.lib")

GLuint program;
GLint attribute_coord;
GLint uniform_tex;
GLint uniform_color;

struct point {
    GLfloat x;
    GLfloat y;
    GLfloat s;
    GLfloat t;
};

GLuint vbo;

FT_Library ft;
FT_Face face;

const char *fontfilename;

int init_resources()
{

    /* Initialize the FreeType2 library */
    if(FT_Init_FreeType(&ft)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not init freetype library\n");
        return 0;
    }

    /* Load a font */
    if(FT_New_Face(ft, fontfilename, 0, &face)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open font %s\n", fontfilename);
        return 0;
    }

    /* Compile and link the shader program */
    GLint link_ok = GL_FALSE;

    program = text::LoadShader("text.v.glsl", NULL, "text.f.glsl");

    const char* attribute_name;
    attribute_name = "coord";
    attribute_coord = glGetAttribLocation(program, attribute_name);
    if (attribute_coord == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not bind attribute %s\n", attribute_name);
        return 0;
    }

    const char* uniform_name;
    uniform_name = "tex";
    uniform_tex = glGetUniformLocation(program, uniform_name);
    if (uniform_tex == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not bind uniform %s\n", uniform_name);
        return 0;
    }

    uniform_name = "color";
    uniform_color = glGetUniformLocation(program, uniform_name);
    if (uniform_color == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not bind uniform %s\n", uniform_name);
        return 0;
    }

    // Create the vertex buffer object
    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);

    return 1;
}

/**
    * Render text using the currently loaded font and currently set font size.
    * Rendering starts at coordinates (x, y), z is always 0.
    * The pixel coordinates that the FreeType2 library uses are scaled by (sx, sy).
    */
void render_text(const char *text, float x, float y, float sx, float sy) {
    const char *p;
    FT_GlyphSlot g = face->glyph;

    /* Create a texture that will be used to hold one "glyph" */
    GLuint tex;
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glGenTextures(1, &tex);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
    glUniform1i(uniform_tex, 0);

    /* We require 1 byte alignment when uploading texture data */
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);

    /* Clamping to edges is important to prevent artifacts when scaling */
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    /* Linear filtering usually looks best for text */
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    /* Set up the VBO for our vertex data */
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(attribute_coord);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glVertexAttribPointer(attribute_coord, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    /* Loop through all characters */
    for(p = text; *p; p++) {
        /* Try to load and render the character */
        if(FT_Load_Char(face, *p, FT_LOAD_RENDER))
            continue;

        /* Upload the "bitmap", which contains an 8-bit grayscale image, as an alpha texture */
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_ALPHA, g->bitmap.width, g->bitmap.rows, 0, GL_ALPHA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, g->bitmap.buffer);

        /* Calculate the vertex and texture coordinates */
        float x2 = x + g->bitmap_left * sx;
        float y2 = -y - g->bitmap_top * sy;
        float w = g->bitmap.width * sx;
        float h = g->bitmap.rows * sy;

        point box[4] = {
            {x2,     -y2    , 0, 0},
            {x2 + w, -y2    , 1, 0},
            {x2,     -y2 - h, 0, 1},
            {x2 + w, -y2 - h, 1, 1},
        };

        /* Draw the character on the screen */
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof box, box, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

        /* Advance the cursor to the start of the next character */
        x += (g->advance.x >> 6) * sx;
        y += (g->advance.y >> 6) * sy;
    }

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(attribute_coord);
    glDeleteTextures(1, &tex);
}

void display()
{
    float sx = 2.0 / glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH);
    float sy = 2.0 / glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT);

    glUseProgram(program);

    /* White background */
    glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    /* Enable blending, necessary for our alpha texture */
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    GLfloat black[4] = {0, 0, 0, 1};
    GLfloat red[4] = {1, 0, 0, 1};
    GLfloat transparent_green[4] = {0, 1, 0, 0.5};

    /* Set font size to 48 pixels, color to black */
    FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes(face, 0, 48);
    glUniform4fv(uniform_color, 1, black);

    /* Effects of alignment */
    render_text("The Quick Brown Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog",          -1 + 8 * sx,   1 - 50 * sy,    sx, sy);
    render_text("The Misaligned Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog",           -1 + 8.5 * sx, 1 - 100.5 * sy, sx, sy);

    /* Scaling the texture versus changing the font size */
    render_text("The Small Texture Scaled Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog", -1 + 8 * sx,   1 - 175 * sy,   sx * 0.5, sy * 0.5);
    FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes(face, 0, 24);
    render_text("The Small Font Sized Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog",     -1 + 8 * sx,   1 - 200 * sy,   sx, sy);
    FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes(face, 0, 48);
    render_text("The Tiny Texture Scaled Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog",  -1 + 8 * sx,   1 - 235 * sy,   sx * 0.25, sy * 0.25);
    FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes(face, 0, 12);
    render_text("The Tiny Font Sized Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog",      -1 + 8 * sx,   1 - 250 * sy,   sx, sy);
    FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes(face, 0, 48);

    /* Colors and transparency */
    render_text("The Solid Black Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog",          -1 + 8 * sx,   1 - 430 * sy,   sx, sy);

    glUniform4fv(uniform_color, 1, red);
    render_text("The Solid Red Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog",            -1 + 8 * sx,   1 - 330 * sy,   sx, sy);
    render_text("The Solid Red Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog",            -1 + 28 * sx,  1 - 450 * sy,   sx, sy);

    glUniform4fv(uniform_color, 1, transparent_green);
    render_text("The Transparent Green Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog",    -1 + 8 * sx,   1 - 380 * sy,   sx, sy);
    render_text("The Transparent Green Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog",    -1 + 18 * sx,  1 - 440 * sy,   sx, sy);

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void free_resources()
{
    glDeleteProgram(program);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    glutInitContextVersion (3, 2);
    glutInitContextFlags (GLUT_FORWARD_COMPATIBLE | GLUT_DEBUG);
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA|GLUT_ALPHA|GLUT_DOUBLE);
    glutInitWindowSize(640, 480);
    glutCreateWindow("Basic Text");

    if(argc > 1)
        fontfilename = argv[1];
    else
        fontfilename = "FreeSans.ttf";

    GLenum glew_status = glewInit();
    if (GLEW_OK != glew_status) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", glewGetErrorString(glew_status));
        return 1;
    }

    if (!GLEW_VERSION_2_0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "No support for OpenGL 2.0 found\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if (init_resources()) {
        glutDisplayFunc(display);
        glutMainLoop();
    }

    free_resources();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`GL_ALPHA` is not a valid [image format](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Format) in GL 3.2 core, hence [the `GL_INVALID_ENUM` error](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GL_Error_Codes). If you want a single-channel image format, then you must use a valid single-channel image format. Namely, some from of `GL_RED` bitdepth. I would suggest `GL_R8`.

This also means that the [pixel transfer format](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Pixel_Transfer#Pixel_format) (the third parameter from the end) must also be `GL_RED`.

Note that those tutorials only work for 3.2+ when you use a compatibility profile. They're not forward compatible, because they have to be compatible with GL ES.

Comment: That seems to have done the trick, thanks! I am now getting GL_INVALID_OPERATION errors with my glDrawArrays call though, due to this: `GL_INVALID_OPERATION is generated if a non-zero buffer object name is bound to an
            enabled array and the buffer object's data store is currently mapped. ` Does this mean I need a seperate vertex buffer object for each glDrawArrays call? Also, I am using a VAO, but do I need seperate buffers for vertices and UV coordinates?
        `

Comment: @AndrewKlein: It means exactly what it says: you cannot pull from a buffer if you've also mapped that buffer.